# How can I download a file from S3 to local network drive using lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS Lambda (python) function that is set to trigger on S3 Object Create.  What I am trying to do is push the created file to a network drive through our VPC but I am not entirely sure how to configure this or the python code to map a shared drive through the VPC. Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Have you checked boto3?

Comment: Lambda won't support in mounting a shared drive. If you can implement an API and expose it to the VPC where the Lambda can upload via the API, it should work. This will require to place the Lambda within the particular VPC.

Comment: I am using boto3 to connect to the AWS S3 file and can read the file.  My lambda function is enabled to use the VPC, I am just wondering if someone has a code example to write a file to a local network share from Lambda using the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Accessing the file (Object created event) from Lambda Python Code can be done through Boto3 Library. AWS SDK for Python

Step 2: Configuring your lambda function for VPC - to be done on the Console or through CLI when you create the lambda function. On the Lamda Function Details Page, there is a "Network" block of UI containing a drop down called "VPC". VPC End Points will be listed here and to be selected.